# Sending data to a webserver with GPRS/GPS Shield (U-blox Sara G-350)

Tags: arduino-uno, shields, gsm

I am working on a project for tracking cars. I am using an Arduino UNO to receive the position from GPS/GPRS shield. I am OK on obtaining the coordinates position.
Now I need to send the position to a webserver and then show it on a webpage using the Google Maps API. Which accepts it in a POST or GET method.
Here is the shield model:
[U-blox Sara G-350](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HfhAU.jpg)
and this is its manual [here](https://www.u-blox.com/sites/default/files/u-blox-ATCommands_Manual_(UBX-13002752).pdf)

Here is my approach:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <String.h>


SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7 ,8);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  gprsSerial.begin(19200);                
  Serial.begin(19200);     
  delay(2000);

 gprsSerial.println("AT+CGDCONT=3,\"IP\",\"weborange\"");
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);

 gprsSerial.println("AT+UHTTP=0");
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);
 gprsSerial.println("AT+UHTTP=2,1,\"www.navtec.16mb.com\"");
                   //AT+UHTTP=<profile_id>,<op_code>,<HTTP_server_name>
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);

 gprsSerial.println("AT+UHTTP=0,5,80");
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);

}

void loop() {

 //gprsSerial.println("AT+UHTTP=2,1,\"submit\"");
                    //AT+UHTTP=<profile_id>,<op_code>,<param_val>[,<param_val1>]
 //toSerial();
 //delay(2000);

 gprsSerial.println("AT+UHTTPC=2,1,\"/add.php\",\"filename\"");  //Problem here!!!!!!!!
                   //AT+UHTTPC=<profile_id>,<http_command>,<path>,<filename>[,<param1>[,<param2>[,<param3>]]]
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.write(gprsSerial.read());
  }

}
```

This is what I get:

> +CGDCONT=3,"IP","weborange"
>
> OK
>   +UHTTP=0
>
> OK
>   +UHTTP=2,1,"www.navtec.16mb.com"
>
> OK
>   +UHTTP=0,5,80
>
> OK
>   +UHTTPC=2,1,/add.php,filename
>
> ERROR
>   +UHTTPC=2,1,/add.php,filename
>
> ERROR
>   +UHTTPC=2,1,/add.php,filename
>
> ERROR
>   +UHTTPC=2,1,/add.php,filename
>
> ERROR ...

Thanks for your time, I am waiting for your support, any ideas could help. Sorry for my bad English

Comment: The examples in the manual have quotes around the PHP file and the filename - just like you have for the FQDN entry. Maybe you should add them...?

Comment: Thank you for your support, but my problem is in the meaning and  perpose of **responseFilename** and how could i work with it?

Comment: Your problem is that you have an error. The filename is where to store the response in the internal filesystem, and the word filename is perfectly valid - as long as you **use quotes around your strings**.

Comment: even when  i add the quotes it still giving me an error. please check my new modification in code.

Comment: Try using AT+UHTTPER to get the error code from the request, see if that helps.

Comment: it work perfectly for me right now,I just get my error with this command.Thanks again @Majenko .I will add the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on a project similar to yours. I think you forgot to **establish a connection first**.
Just add those lines of code at the top of `setup()` method:

```
 gprsSerial.println("AT+UPSDA=2,0"); //Reset connection
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);
  gprsSerial.println("AT+UPSD=2,1,\"weborange\""); //Establish a new one
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);
 gprsSerial.println("AT+UPSDA=2,3"); 
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);
 gprsSerial.println("AT+UPSND=2,0");
 toSerial();
 delay(2000);
```

I hope it works for you. Else, you can use `AT+UHTTPER=2` after all to check for error source.